# yacc/lex segfaulting at end of tokens, but only sometimes

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, grammar, yacc, lex

EDIT:
Solved. Its a problem with my home made vector that is clobbering memory and causing weird things to happen.

I'm a bit stumped at why my yacc/lex program is segfaulting.
I've made a small language grammar where an expression can be EXPR AND EXPR. It segfaults if I do:
`myFunc(x) = x;`
But it doesnt segfault if I do:
`myFunc(x) = x, x;`
Whats more strange is that if I do a single expression that is a function call:
`myFunc(x) = someFunc(x);`
then its fine.

The main points of iterest in my yacc file are:

```
Func_def : Func_head Exprs END {
    function f = $1;
    f.e = $2;
    insert_at(func_defs, 0, &f);
};

Exprs
    : Expr {
        $$ = $1;
    }
    | Expr AND Exprs {
        expr lhs = $1;
        expr rhs = $3;
        expr ex;
        ex.type = e_and;
        ex.e.n.lhs = malloc(sizeof(expr));
        ex.e.n.rhs = malloc(sizeof(expr));
        memcpy(ex.e.n.lhs, &lhs, sizeof(lhs));
        memcpy(ex.e.n.rhs, &rhs, sizeof(rhs));
        $$ = ex;
    }
    ;

Expr : Fcall    { expr ex; ex.type = e_fcall; ex.e.f = $1; $$ = ex; }
     | Var      { expr ex; ex.type = e_var;   ex.e.v = $1; $$ = ex; }
     | Atom     { expr ex; ex.type = e_atom;  ex.e.a = $1; $$ = ex; }
     | Equation { expr ex; ex.type = e_equ;   ex.e.e = $1; $$ = ex; }
     ;

Fcall : WORD LP_ROUND Params RP_ROUND {
    fcall fc;
    fc.name = $1;
    fc.params = $3;
    $$ = fc;
};

Var : WORD {
    var v;
    v.symbol = $1;
    $$ = v;
};
```

I've stepped through with gdb and found the following:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
yylex () at lex.yy.c:805
805                     if ( YY_CURRENT_BUFFER_LVALUE->yy_buffer_status == YY_BUFFER_NEW )
(gdb) backtrace
#0  yylex () at lex.yy.c:805
#1  0x0000555555557dc3 in yyparse () at y.tab.c:1268
#2  0x0000555555558cef in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe838) at main.c:27
```

I also enabled debugging and verbose mode in yacc with --debug and --verbose, but state machine looks like its running perfectly, but then just continues to read tokens after the end and segfaults.
My lex file is pretty stock standard, but ill add it incase im missing something.

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "internal_struct.h"
    #include "y.tab.h"
%}
%%
[0-9]+ {
    yylval.number = atoi(yytext);
    return NUMBER;
}
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* {
    yylval.string = strdup(yytext);
    return WORD;
}
['('] return LP_ROUND;
[')'] return RP_ROUND;
[','] return AND;
['='] return EQUAL;
[';'] return END;
[\t | ' '] ;
[\n] ;
. return yytext[0];
%%
int yywrap() {
    return 1;
}
```

My best guess is that its something simple that im missing but maybe i've got tunnel vision now.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Ive compared the debug output between a segfaulting parse and working parse, and have noticed that instead of recognising en eof, it crashes. Eg:
A good run:

```
...
Stack now 0
Entering state 3
Reading a token: Now at end of input.
Reducing stack by rule 1 (line 50):
...
```

A crash run:

```
...
Stack now 0
Entering state 3
Reading a token:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

Comment: Without seeing an entire program (including struct definitions) it's hard to even make a hypothesis, although my inclination is memory corruption. (If that were the case, valgrind might help). There's some suspicious stuff going on there. For example, `insert_at(func_defs, 0, &f);` passes a pointer to a local variable which at least looks like a dangling pointer.

Comment: Yes thats my next thought. Im looking through carefully just incase.
The ```insert_at``` is a vector that ive made, just to make storing things easier. I have a test suit for it and everything passes, but I am also suspicious of it.

Comment: By the way, single quote has no special significance in (f)lex patterns. Double quote is the quote symbol, but it doesn't do anything special inside a character class.  Anyway there is no need to escape most characters inside a character class (the backslash itself is an important exception). So most of your single character patterns actually also match a single quote, and `[\t | ' '] ;` matches any one of four characters: tab, space, `|` and `'`. That's unlikely to have anything to do with your problem but you should probably take a quick look at the flex pattern docs and fix your patterns.

Comment: If you're using linux, you should definitely try valgrind to detect potential overwrite errors. If you want a more informed opinion, please provide a [mre] (i.e. a self-contained compilable project).

Comment: Woah thank for the heads up about the quotes.
Okay, im going to try valgrind first, then ill do a minimal example. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Yep youre right, something going wrong with my vector and memory is getting clobbered. Valgrind pointed me in the right direction. If I set my vector to an initial size of 100, then everything works fine. So its not a problem with my yacc/lex.
Thanks heaps for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The lexer must detect EOF and generate a suitable token that must then unambiguously end the top/outermost production in the grammar. The parser needs to know to stop.

Comment: hmm okay, that makes sense to me.
So now im trying to add in eof with:<br>
```<<EOF>> { 
    printf("found eof");
    yyterminate();
};```<br>
But that token is never matched, even if I feed it something that doesnt crash.
Would you say this is the best way to do eof?

Comment: This is not correct. Flex's default action on end of file is to return 0, and bison parsers treat 0 as an unambiguous end of input indication.

Comment: So does that mean I dont actually have to do anything, and yyparse() will just terminate automatically on eof?

Comment: @tristus: yes. Trying to handle eof is far more likely to get you into trouble than letting the defaults work. Personally, I wouldn't use `END` as a token name, but I don't think it's a problem with recent bison versions. It's a bit confusing for human readers, though.